# Git alias with argument

Tags: git, command-line-interface, alias

My team works on separate branches and, commonly, I need to switch from branches quickly to help them. But I need to spend a lot of time finding which branch they are working on and I need to retype the whole branch names (and they are very long).

So I found a handy command that lets me get the branch name without cycling through the whole list:
`git branch -a | find "72"` and it returns me this: `remotes/origin/72-js-remove-the-player-from-the-game`. Our branch names always have the merge request number of GitLab in the front of the name, so it's always a unique number.

I would like to shorten this to a simple `git find 20`. I thought that git CLI was similar to bash shell but to add aliases with arguments, I need to access `.bashrc` (Which I'm unable to find for the Git CLI).

Also, I would like to maybe shorten the whole process of searching for a branch, retyping it into the CLI and switching to it with a single command similar to that (something like `git qswitch 20`), if that's possible.

Comment: https://jondavidjohn.com/git-aliases-parameters/

Comment: `git` doesn't have a CLI of its own. It's a command that you run *from* another shell.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about aliasing like the way you requested but there is an alias option in the git config where you can do something similar

```
git config --global alias.fin 'branch -a | find'
```

> Git doesn’t automatically infer your command if you type it in
>   partially. If you don’t want to type the entire text of each of the
>   Git commands, you can easily set up an alias for each command using
>   git config.

I am not sure how well it would work with piping to be honest

So basically your command would become git fin "72"

refer https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases
https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/advanced-git-aliases

Edit: thanks to @torek

If we wanted to use pipes the above method would not actually work, here is a working example

`git config --global alias.fin !f(){\ git branch -a | find $1 ; \};f`

Comment: To get shell-like capabilities, such as pipes, in a Git alias, you must invoke the shell from that Git alias (leading `!` in the expansion).

Comment: Hey thanks, I did some digging into what you said. And have edited the answer to include that